# Error on standard new record create button on list view in Winter 21

Tags: lightning-web-components, create-records, standard, winter21

You get following error in technical description.
When creating a new record using standard New button on a given list view in Winter'21 orgs for specific record types only

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: LWC component's @wire target property or method threw an error during value provisioning. Original error:
[Cannot assign to read only property 'value' of object '#<Object>']
    at kn.set (aura_prod.js:12)
    at e.RecordDraft.reinitializeField (recordUiUtils.js:1)
    at re.initialize (recordUiUtils.js:1)
    at e.RecordDraft.initializeDependentPicklistManagement (recordUiUtils.js:1)
    at detailPanel_Prs_Communication__c___012000000000000AAA___Full___Create___RecordLayout2.createRecordDraft (recordLayout2.js:1)
    at y (recordLayout2.js:1)
    at eval (recordLayout2.js:1)
    at detailPanel_Prs_Communication__c___012000000000000AAA___Full___Create___RecordLayout2.finishDataInitialization (recordLayout2.js:1)
    at L (recordLayout2.js:1)
    at detailPanel_Prs_Communication__c___012000000000000AAA___Full___Create___RecordLayout2.handleGetCreateCloneRecord (recordLayout2.js:1)
```

Note: You don't get the error when clicking on new button on a related list, just the list view New button, also not when creating new records using Aura force:createRecord action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the looks of the error there seems to be something going wrong with dependent picklist.
In our case we had two picklist fields - Stage and Sub Stage, where Sub Stage dependent on Stage field.
And the peculiar thing was that sub stage had a default value set on certain record types, but nothing was defaulting on the main Stage picklist for that given record type.

After removing default value for the Sub stage picklist for the given record type, this got resolved.